# Two dependent dropdown and text areas (4 text area) depending on the last dropdown from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

[image]

1st dropdown select distinct from table
2nd dropdown select sub category from table where category is like the first dropdown

then after selection of second dropdown, 4 text field must automatically fill with data also

please help

My `PHP`:

```
global $wpdb; 
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT article from wp_rpci_description"); 
echo "<label id='select'><select name='article'>"; 
foreach ($rows as $row 
{ 
  echo "<option>$row->article</option>"; 
} 
echo "</select></label>";
```

And my `html`:

```
<tr>
  <th>Description</th>
  <td>
    <select name='article'>
      <option>
        <?php echo $description;?>
      </option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Stocknumber</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="stocknumber" value="<?php echo $stocknumber;?>" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Unit of Measure</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="unitofmeasure" value="<?php echo $unitofmeasure;?>" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Unit Value</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="unitvalue" value="<?php echo $unitvalue;?>" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Balance per Card (Quantity)</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="balancepercard" value="<?php echo $balancepercard;?>" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Onhand per Count (Quantity)</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="onhandpercount" value="<?php echo $onhandpercount;?>" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Shortage/Overage Quantity</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="soquantity" value="<?php echo $soquantity;?>" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Shortage/Overage Value</th>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="sovalue" value="<?php echo $sovalue;?>" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Remarks</th>
  <td>
    <textarea name="remarks">
      <?php echo $remarks;?>
    </textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="userids" value="<?php echo $user_id;?>" />
  </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: <?php
global $wpdb;
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT article from wp_rpci_description");
 echo "<label id='select'><select name='article'>";

foreach ($rows as $row ){
 echo "<option>$row->article</option>";
 }
echo "</select></label>";
?>

Comment: sorry to bad coding styles

Comment: add it to your question.Never in comments.

Comment: sorry I'm new here and thank you for the edit.

Comment: This is not asking us to *help* it's asking *will you write these features for me?* At a glance, I'd say you'll need to, get the value from the select, then  look into jQuery's `.ajax()` which you can use to send that value to a php script that uses it to run a query, return the query results to the ajax success callback which should then build or populate another select box with options from those results

Comment: @RoginThomas you just removed the OP's image!

Comment: I use some ajax and it was just populate the select option, what i cant get is to put the data into input and send it as a regular form

Answer (score 0):

call a ajax request on change of 2nd dropdown,

```
$('#dropdown2_id').live('change', function(event) {
    var dropdown1=$(this).val();
    var dropdown2=$("#dropdown1").val();
    $.ajax({
            url:"filename.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data:{'dropdown1':dropdown1,'dropdown2':dropdown2},
            success: function(data){
               $('.input-class').val(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have to put IDs on the select?, what should I put on filename.php?,
sorry newbie in coding

Comment: Check this example : http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/

Comment: I tried those and it works before my problem now is how to populate the text areas

Comment: add class in input field eg: <input type="text" class="class-stocknumber" name="stocknumber" value="<?php echo $stocknumber;?>" />

Comment: then using json, pass value from php.